# Drag and drop elements between two drop zones in R shiny

Tags: css, r, shiny, drag-and-drop

I am trying to use `shiny` to drag and drop elements from one column to another in a dynamic document.

However, I could not identify a way:

- to have the `A`, `B`, `C` elements in one of the boxes (drop zones) at launch
- to make the boxes fill to the bottom of the webpage.

Below is the code I am using:

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyDND)

ui <- shinyUI(fillPage(
fillRow(
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      h1("Side panel"),
      dropUI(
      "side_panel", row_n = 2, col_n = 1
    ),
    br(),
    verbatimTextOutput("side"),
    width = 6
    ),
    mainPanel(
      h1("Main panel"),
      div(dragUI("div6", "A"), style = "margin-left:-90%"),
      div(dragUI("div6", "B"), style = "margin-left:-90%"),
      div(dragUI("div5", "C"), style = "margin-left:-90%"),
      dropUI("main_panel", row_n = 2, col_n = 6),
      br(),
      verbatimTextOutput("main"),
      width = 6
    ),
    position = "right",
    fluid = FALSE
  )
)))

server = shinyServer(function(input, output,session) {
  observeEvent(input$main_panel,{
    output$main = renderText(
      paste("The main dropUI element currently contains:", input$main_panel, sep = " "))
  })
  observeEvent(input$side_panel,{
    output$side = renderText(
      paste("The side dropUI element currently contains:", input$side_panel, sep = " "))
  })
})

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: "to make the boxes fill to the bottom of the webpage.": Do you mean the drop zones where `A`, `B` and `C` shall be placed? If so, where do you want to have the panels which display "The main dropUI element currently contains: ..." then? They are currently located below the boxes.

Comment: I would like actually to have the draggable elements within two columns (initially say the right one), and to be able to move them freely from one to the other.

Comment: Are you limited to `shinyDND` or is a solution using another package also acceptable (`sortable`)?

Comment: Thank you for your help. No, I am not limited.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As already indicated in the comments, I would suggest to use the `sortable` library for drag and drop in `shiny`. Below is one example where the requirement is fulfilled that the `A`, `B` and `C` elements are initially located in the right zone.

Notice that for the GIF I added some `CSS` such that the style of the zones and elements looks similar to your given example and that I set the `height` style of the `.rank-list` selector to `30vh`. You can fully customise this, in particular you can adjust it such that the boxes fill to the bottom of the webpage.

[image]

```
library(shiny)
library(sortable)

ui <- shinyUI(
    fillPage(
        tags$head(
            tags$style(HTML("
                            .rank-list {
                                height:30vh;
                                border:dashed;
                            }
                            
                            .rank-list-item {
                                width:40px;
                                margin-left:140px;
                                margin-top:10px;
                            }
 
                            .default-sortable .rank-list.rank-list-empty {
                                border-color: black
                            }
                            "))
        ),
        fillRow(sidebarLayout(
            sidebarPanel(
                h1("Side panel"),
                bucket_list(
                    header = NULL,
                    group_name = "bucket_list_group",
                    orientation = "horizontal",
                    add_rank_list(
                        text = "Drag items from here ...",
                        labels = list("A",
                                      "B",
                                      "C"),
                        input_id = "rank_list_1"
                    )
                ),
                br(),
                verbatimTextOutput("results_2"),
                width = 6
            ),
            mainPanel(
                br(),
                h1("Main panel"),
                bucket_list(
                    header = NULL,
                    group_name = "bucket_list_group",
                    orientation = "horizontal",
                    add_rank_list(
                        text = "... to here",
                        labels = NULL,
                        input_id = "rank_list_2"
                    )
                ),
                br(),
                verbatimTextOutput("results_1"),
                width = 6
            ),
            position = "right",
            fluid = FALSE
        ))))

server = shinyServer(function(input, output, session) {
    output$results_1 <-
        renderText(paste(
            "The main dropUI element contains:",
            paste(input$rank_list_2, collapse = ", ")
        ))
    
    output$results_2 <-
        renderText(paste(
            "The side dropUI element contains:",
            paste(input$rank_list_1, collapse = ", ")
        ))
})

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```